# Spring Batch 3.0 : StepExecutionListener for a partitioned Step and cascading of execution context values to the partitioned job

Tags: java, spring-batch, listener, partitioning

Given a *Spring Batch* Job that uses partitioning :

```
<job id="reportingJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
        <batch:listeners>
            <batch:listener ref="reportingJobExecutionListenerr" />
        </batch:listeners>
        <batch:step id="reportingMasterStep">
            <partition step="reportingSlaveStep"
                partitioner="reportingPartitioner">
                <batch:handler grid-size="10" task-executor="taskExecutor" />
            </partition>
        </batch:step>
</job>
```

And `reportingSlaveStep` defined as :

```
<step id="reportingSlaveStep" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
        <job ref="reportingSlaveJob" />
</step>
```

And `reportingSlaveJob` defined as :

```
    <job id="reportingSlaveJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
        <batch:listeners>
            <batch:listener ref="reportsOutputListener" />
        </batch:listeners>
        <batch:split id="reportsCreationSplit"
            task-executor="taskExecutor">
            <batch:flow>
                <batch:step id="basicReportStep">
                    <tasklet throttle-limit="5" task-executor="taskExecutor">
                        <batch:chunk reader="basicReportReader"
                            writer="basicReportWriter" commit-interval="500" />
                    </tasklet>
                </batch:step>
            </batch:flow>
            <batch:flow>
                <batch:step id="advancedReportStep">
                    <tasklet throttle-limit="5" task-executor="taskExecutor">
                        <batch:chunk reader="advancedReportDataReader" writer="advancedReportWriter"
                            commit-interval="500" />
                    </tasklet>
                </batch:step>
            </batch:flow>
       </batch:split>
     </job>
```

I now have 2 questions :

1. I want a new `reportsOutputListener` instance to be created for each partition. Can I achieve this by making `reportsOutputListener` a `Step` scoped bean?
2. I want to be able to access the same `jobExecutionContext` created for  `reportingJob` to be accessible in `reportingSlaveJob`. Do I need to any special handling for this or is the same `jobExecutionContext` instance in `reportingJob` is used by the `reportingSlaveStepSlaveJob` as well?
3. **EDIT** : When I run the above job, at times I get an exception saying that the "A job execution for this job is already running" and other times I get a `NullPointerException` on `MapExecutionContextDao.java:130`.

**EDIT** : Also note that for point 2, the `slaveJob` is unable to access the values added in the `stepExecutionContext` (access using `#{stepExecutionContext['msbfBatchId']}` in spring config xml)  by the `reportingPartitioner`. The values in the `stepExecutionContext` against the key come out as `null`.

Comment: For question 1 the answer is yes. For question 2, I will need to have a working example to play with, but my thinking is the following: since the sub job (reportingSlaveJob) is a nothing but a step (of type JobStep), it should be possible somehow to access the parent execution context of the master job (reportingJob) as soon as the step execution of the sub job is in scope (in which case `stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext()` will give the execution context you are looking for).

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Looks like I had to do some special handling for cascading the values from the `reportingJob` to the `reportingSlaveJob ` after all. I had to write a custom `JobParametersExtractor` since the `DefaultJobParametersExtractor` in *Spring Batch* 3.0 was not copying the job execution context data to the `jobParameters` of the `reportingSlaveJob` for some reason.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Thanks for the response. Please see my edit. For 2) All values added to the stepExecutionContext by the reportingPartitioner are coming out as null. (Accessed using #{stepExecutionContext['myKey']}) in spring xml config). Also added point 3 indicating this kind of setup doesn't seem to be working. I am using Spring Batch 3.0. I now have nly one outstanding issue that needs to be resolved. `jobExecution.getExecutionContext` returns `null` in `reportsOutputListener` which is a step scoped job execution listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want a new reportsOutputListener instance to be created for each
>   partition. Can I achieve this by making reportsOutputListener a Step
>   scoped bean?

The answer is **Yes**. (as mentioned in the comments by [Mahmoud Ben Hassine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5019386/mahmoud-ben-hassine))

> I want to be able to access the same jobExecutionContext created for
>   reportingJob to be accessible in reportingSlaveJob. Do I need to any
>   special handling for this or is the same jobExecutionContext instance
>   in reportingJob is used by the reportingSlaveStepSlaveJob as well?

The answer is **No**. I dug into the *Spring Batch* code and found that `JobStep` uses a `JobParametersExtractor` for copying the values from the `stepExecutionContext` to the `JobParameters`. This means that `reportingSlaveJob` can access these values from the `JobParameters` instead of the `StepExecutionContext`. That said, for some reason, the `DefaultJobParametersExtractor` implementation in *Srping Batch 3.0* doesn't seem to be copying the values to the `jobParameters` as expected. I ended up writing the following cusom extractor :

```
public class CustomJobParametersExtractor implements JobParametersExtractor {

    private Set<String> keys;

    public CustomJobParametersExtractor () {
        this.keys = new HashSet<>();
    }

    @Override
    public JobParameters getJobParameters(Job job, StepExecution stepExecution) {
        JobParametersBuilder builder = new JobParametersBuilder();
        Map<String, JobParameter> jobParameters = stepExecution.getJobParameters().getParameters();
        ExecutionContext stepExecutionContext = stepExecution.getExecutionContext();
        ExecutionContext jobExecutionContext = stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext();

        // copy job parameters from parent job to delegate job
        for (String key : jobParameters.keySet()) {
            builder.addParameter(key, jobParameters.get(key));
        }

        // copy job/step context from parent job/step to delegate job
        for (String key : keys) {
            if (jobExecutionContext.containsKey(key)) {
                builder.addString(key, jobExecutionContext.getString(key));
            } else if (stepExecutionContext.containsKey(key)) {
                builder.addString(key, stepExecutionContext.getString(key));
            } else if (jobParameters.containsKey(key)) {
                builder.addString(key, (String) jobParameters.get(key).getValue());
            }
        }
        return builder.toJobParameters();
    }

    public void setKeys(String[] keys) {
        this.keys = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(keys));
    }

}
```

I can then use the above extractor in the reporting slave step as follows :

```
<step id="reportingSlaveStep" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
        <job ref="reportingSlaveJob" job-parameters-extractor="customJobParametersExtractor"/>
</step>
```

where `customJobParametersExtractor` is a bean of type `CustomJobParametersExtractor` which is passed all the keys that we want to copy to the `JobParameters` of `reportingSlaveJob`.

> When I run the above job, at times I get an exception saying that the
>   "A job execution for this job is already running" and other times I
>   get a NullPointerException on MapExecutionContextDao.java:130

The reason this was happening was because **WITHOUT** my `CustomJobParameterExtractor`, the `reportingSlaveJob` was getting launched with empty `JobParameters`. For *Spring Batch* to create a new job instance, the job parameters have to be different for each launch of the `reportingSlaveJob`. Using the `CustomJobParameterExtractor` fixed this issue as well.